# php countdown based on the current date?

Tags: php, countdown

I want to make a countdown, which counts to the next first friday in a month.
So if we have the 1st august the next friday is the 3rd august, but if we have the 5th august the next friday would be the September 7th.

```
<?php
    $help=strtotime(date('Y')+date('m')+'-00 next friday');
    if (time()*1000 > $help* 1000+(18*60*60*1000)) {
        $count = strtotime(date('Y')+'-'+date('m')+'-00 next friday') * 1000+(18*60*60*1000);
        //case month is passed i need the next month 
    }
    else {
        $count = strtotime(date('Y')+'-'+date('m')+'-00 next friday') * 1000+(18*60*60*1000);
         //case actual month first friday isn't passed need current month
    }
?>
```

That is the code i actual have, but there are mistakes in the 4th and in the 8th line. Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: What 'Mistakes' is it saying you've made in your logs. Also does it have to be in PHP? what are you using the timer to do? be more specific

Comment: it says there is a non numeric value in these lines

Comment: it should count down to the first friday in the month and if this friday is passed it should count down to the friday in the next months

Answer (score 1):

Given a valid date you can proceed like this to know the next Friday:

```
    $date= '2018-08-31 06:30';
    $strtotime=strtotime($date);
    $start=date_create($date);
    do{ 
        $strtotime=strtotime($start->add( date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }while(date('l',$strtotime)!='Friday');

print($start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

the output will be :

```
2018-09-07 06:30:00
```

for the countdown you can proceed like this given the same date or whatever you want (this must follow the code above):

```
$start->setTime(0,0);
$countdown = date_diff($start,date_create($date));
$days = $countdown->d>1?'days':'day';
$hours = $countdown->h>1?'hours':'hour';
$minutes = $countdown->i>1?'minutes':'minute';
$countdown = $countdown->format("%D $days %H $hours %I $minutes");
print_r($countdown);
```

the output is :

```
06 days 17 hours 30 minutes
```

Finally based on explanations above your full script for the countdown could be:

```
$date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//you can put any valid date here
$date_prime=$date;
$strtotime=strtotime($date);
$start=date_create($date);
$start->setDate((int)date('Y',$strtotime),(int)date('m',$strtotime),1);
$start->setTime(0,0);
do{
    $strtotime=strtotime($start->add( date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}while(date('l',$strtotime)!='Friday');
$readable_format=$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if(strtotime($readable_format)>$strtotime){
    $countdown=date_diff($start,date_create($date_prime));
    $days=$countdown->d>1?'days':'day';
    $hours=$countdown->h>1?'hours':'hour';
    $minutes=$countdown->i>1?'minutes':'minute';
    $countdown=$countdown->format("%D $days %H $hours %I $minutes");
}
else{
    $start->setDate((int)date('Y',$strtotime),(int)date('m',$strtotime),(int)date('t',$strtotime));
    do{
        $strtotime=strtotime($start->add( date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }while(date('l',$strtotime)!='Friday');
    $readable_format=$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $countdown=date_diff($start,date_create($date_prime));
    $days=$countdown->d>1?'days':'day';
    $hours=$countdown->h>1?'hours':'hour';
    $minutes=$countdown->i>1?'minutes':'minute';
    $countdown=$countdown->format("%D $days %H $hours %I $minutes");
}
print_r($countdown); will actually give:
24 days 23 hours 55 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to countdown to an event use this code and adapt it to your needs

```
// Todays date
$today = time();

// Day you want to reach
$event = mktime(0,0,0,12,25,2018);

// Calculates days until event
$countdown = round(($event - $today)/86400);

echo "$countdown days until whatever";
```

?>

Comment: yeah the problem is that I haven't a fixed date it's variabel if one friday is passed the next shout be used for the countdown without a change in the .php file

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

```
 <?php
    $help=strtotime("first friday of this month");
    if (time()*1000 > $help* 1000+(18*60*60*1000)) {
        $count = strtotime("first friday of next month") * 1000+(18*60*60*1000);
    }
    else {
        $count =  strtotime('next friday')* 1000+(18*60*60*1000);
    }
?>
```